# NASM assembly to Binary converter

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have made a file.asm that has assembly code and would like to get the binary code of that file.  I have been using the command line

```
nasm -f bin file.asm
```

When I run this command no files are generated and no binary code is displayed.  Where would I find this?

Thanks All!

Comment: Did you try this? nasm -f bin file.asm -o file.bin.  With hexdump -C file.bin you can see the bytes in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for an [assembly listing](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.02/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.3), not a binary "output file" which is a raw binary opcode file. That's how you *display* the binary codes (as opposed to generating a pure binary file).

```
nasm file.asm -l file.lst
```

Then just open `file.lst` and look at it. It will show all the encoding of all the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The result should by default be written to `file`, ie. whatever you have given as input minus the `.asm` extension. You can also direct the output to any file explicitly by using the `-o` option and you can also ask for listing file. You should have been able to figure this out yourself if you had at least taken a look at the [manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.02/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.1).